# CoreData NSExpression "max:" function behavior on iOS 13.x

Tags: ios, core-data

Suppose we have a very simple entity in the Core Data model with the name "Entity" that has one attribute named "index" of type "Integer 32". And this entity is empty.
And we run this code:

```swift
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = getCoreDataContext()
let maxIndexKeypath = "maxIndex"

let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity")
request.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.dictionaryResultType

let expressionDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
expressionDescription.name = maxIndexKeypath
let keypathExpression = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "index")
expressionDescription.expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "max:", arguments: [keypathExpression])
expressionDescription.expressionResultType = .integer32AttributeType

request.propertiesToFetch = [expressionDescription]
var maxIndex: Int?
do {
    let result = try context.fetch(request) as? [[String: Int32]]
    print(result?.isEmpty)
    print(result)
    if let result = try context.fetch(request) as? [[String: Int32]], let maxIndexDict = result.first {
        maxIndex = maxIndexDict[maxIndexKeypath]?.int
    }
} catch {
    fatalError()
}
print(maxIndex)
```

On **iOS 12.2** results of print's are:

```
Optional(false)
Optional([["maxIndex": 0]])
Optional(0)
```

On **iOS >= 13 (currently iOS 13.2)** results of print's are:

```
Optional(false)
Optional([[:]])
nil
```

**My question:** Is this a bug in iOS 13 (and above) in calculating a max value of attribute in case of empty entity?
**And a second question:** What is the best workaround (if answer for first question is true) for calculating a max value for an empty entity in both cases of iOS - below and above iOS 13?